# Get item value with largest date from array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my database I'm having datasets of the form

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60994d48b223f7553c082ab2"),
    "name" : "name",
    "stateHistory" : [
        {
            "state" : "scanning",
            "date" : {
                "$date" : 1620659528239
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

When returning the list of datasets I want to add a computed field `maxState` that displays the value of the oldest `state` entry from the `stateHistory`.

I successfully managed to get the oldest date entry from the `stateHistory` by using something like:

```
db.datasets.aggregate( [
   {
     $addFields: {
            maxState: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
                "$stateHistory",
                {
                    $indexOfArray: [
                        "$stateHistory.date",
                        { $max: "$stateHistory.date" },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        }
    }
   }
])
```

However, this would return the whole object with the largest age

```
{
    "state" : "scanning",
    "date" : {
        "$date" : 1620659528239
    }
}
```

instead of its `state` value (i.e. `"scanning"`)

I have searched the whole mongodb documentation, but I can't find any method to access a specific value from an object key.

What would be the best approach to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to tell `$arrayElemAt` that you want `"$stateHistory.state"`'s specific element,

```
db.datasets.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      maxState: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$stateHistory.state", // change here
          {
            $indexOfArray: [
              "$stateHistory.date",
              {
                $max: "$stateHistory.date"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/egpNJkvN1w_)